# Sort with multiple columns in mongoose using AND operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a videos collection which have like(count), share(count), and comment(array) and I want to sort all the videos according to the maximum likes, shares and comments. How would I do that.
Here is my schema:

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
   user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
   message: { type: String, required: true },
   like: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})

var videoSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  video: { type: String, required: true },
  like: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  share: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  comments: [commentSchema]
}, { timestamps: true });

var Video = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema);
module.exports = Video;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `sort` ([Sorting in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)) function like in the following example:

```
Video
  .find({})
  .sort('-like -share -comments')
  .exec((err, _videos) => { ... });
```

Note that `-` sign before field name means `descending`, if omitted, it will sort `ascending` that column.

If you face some issues with your `comments` sorting, add `createdAt` timestamp field and then use `.sort('-like -share -comments.createdAt')`.

Comment: As I can see the result of that code, it is only applied on the first column "like". And I change the order to "-share -like -comments' then it only applied on "share" column. And I want that all three should be maximum.

Comment: And if you try with `.sort({like: -1, share: -1, comments: -1})`?

Comment: Are you sure that you understand how your data should be sorted by `like` and `share` in desc order? It should sort by `like desc` first and when likes are the same between the two rows of data it starts checking for `share` values and pick the one with more shares first. For example we have situation like this: `data=[{like: 10, share: 8}, {like: 12, share: 8}, {like: 10, share: 10}]`... After sort you should have `[{like: 12, share: 8}, {like: 10, share: 10}, {like: 10, share: 8}]`. Is that correct?

Comment: ok and what about the comment. I think the count of comment will be consider, then why are you working with date.

Comment: I'm not sure about the behaviour regarding the `comments` as it's not a simple data (string, number, ...). I guess it will work for the `comments` too if mongoose checks for timestamp generated for each object (`createAt` or something like that). Feel free to test that and let me know if it works.